# VisualStudio shows an error when adding GpuManaged attribute

Tags: c#, aleagpu

I get `Fody/Alea: TODO Transform: ILLabel` error in VS, when trying to compile following code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var gpu = Gpu.Default;
    gpu.For(0, 100, idx => Do(idx));

    Console.ReadKey();
}

[GpuManaged]
public static void Do(int idx)
{
    bool isTrue = false;
    bool one = true;
    bool two = true;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        if (isTrue)
        {
            if (one)
                continue;

            isTrue = false;
        }
        else
        {
            if (two)
                continue;

            isTrue = true;
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

The issue is only reproducible when putting the `[GpuManaged]` attribute.
Also I have noticed that if you remove `if (one) continue;` and `if (two) continue;` then error disappears. How do I fix it?

The code was simplified a lot from my actual solution, but this should be enough to see the issue..

- win 10 x64
- alea 3.0.4
- alea.fody 3.0.4
- fsharp.core 4.3.4
- geforce GT 710

Comment: Marking method with `GpuManaged` makes alea to rewrite your method (on IL level) to work on gpu, and not every nonsense can be converted like this.

Comment: an actual version of the code looks like the one mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49883187/monitor-blinks-and-program-throws-exception-when-using-alea I didn't want people to look at the more complicated version within the scope of this ticket. As they then would have more unrelated questions.. Better keep it as simple as possible.

Comment: Ok, I just thought that maybe you are just playing with alea and not actually have real code, and wanted to point out that not every code can be run this way.

Comment: @Evk Actually, the version of the code which I provided in a link is also a simplified in regards to the fact that the data contains either `0` and `false`s. In real data there all kinds of `doubles`, `bool`eans and `int`egers and also the amount of data that is being processed in a loop is `720mil` of records! It takes around 12 hours to process it on my `CPU`. I have migrated the code to `aleagpu` successfully, except, it keeps throwing me exceptions on every occasion. :) I have created 3 separate issues on SO for every issue I encounter, hoping to resolve at least any of the these..